# Overlay make icon clickable in ready template

Tags: html, hyperlink, overlay, font-awesome, clickable

I would like to know to how to make the search icon or heading clickable in the mouse-over overlay on the pictures in the portfolio section.

Here is the link to the template and all its assets: http://www.templatemo.com/tm-406-flex

Live view: http://www.templatemo.com/live/templatemo_406_flex

And also just the HTML code:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="portfolio-item col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="portfolio-thumb">
            <img src="images/gallery/p1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-overlay">
                <h3>Heading</h3>
                <p>flex is a html theme.</p>
                <a href="images/gallery/p2.jpg" data-rel="lightbox" class="expand">
                   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </a>
            </div> <!-- /.portfolio-overlay -->
        </div> <!-- /.portfolio-thumb -->
    </div> <!-- /.portfolio-item -->
```

Comment: You mean those boat and tricycle pictures should be clickable?

Comment: You can add .click event to those image tags

Comment: Maybe this will help ? https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp

Comment: Thanks for the responses i actually need either the <h3> heading to be clickable which disappears when i try or the font awesome icon too become clickable